# JMeter. Receiving scriptSessionId for DWR requests

Tags: ajax, testing, jmeter, dwr

I've faced a problem that I can't get scriptSessionId using Regular Expression Extractor.

I have an [HTTP request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4AhJ.png) that was recorded using Proxy.
So I've added a regular expression [extractor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhHY8.png) to the engine.js

But this not helps me to get the scriptSessionID.

Any suggestions what is going wrong? I have a feeling like I've put this post-processor too early or too late. Would be really glad if someone could help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> scriptSessionId:(.+?)

Use above Also share your response code too so that i can create Regular expression.

Comment: Here's my [response](https://jpst.it/10o0f) from engine.js. I'm not sure, maybe in this expression should be selected response message or response code instead of the body?

Comment: Okay, already understood that it should be the body. Another question. I've red that engine.js should be GET, not POST. Is it really matters?

Comment: No matters for request type!!